# Set compiler in Code::Blocks on a per project basis

Tags: c++, build-process, codeblocks, g++-4.7

Is it possible to setup the Code::Blocks to use a specified C++ compiler on a per-project basis? It seems to be a Global setting under `Settings->Compiler`. I could always run a custom build script but would like to know if the functionality is already built in to Code::Blocks.

In addition the different compilers are both versions of g++ 4.7 so in particular I really need to set `Toolchain executables->Compiler's installation directory` on a per project basis.

Answer (score 1):

Under Compiler and debugger settings you can clone the existing "GNU GCC Compiler" profile and customize it with the desired gcc version and its location. Afterwards, under your existing project right-click and select "build options". For the "Selected compiler" drop down menu choose the new gcc profile you just cloned.